# Preg Replace in PHP for Heading Tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, markdown

I have a markdown text content which I have to replace without using library functions.So I used preg replace for this.It works fine for some cases.For cases like heading

```
    for eg Heading
           ======= 

should be converted to <h1>Heading</h1> and also

    ##Sub heading should be converted to <h2>Sub heading</h2>
    ###Sub heading should be converted to <h3>Sub heading</h3>
```

I have tried

```
$text = preg_replace('/##(.+?)\n/s', '<h2>$1</h2>', $text);
```

The above code works but I need to have count of hash symbol and based on that I have to assign heading tags.

Anyone help me please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).
Something like this -

```
$regex = '/(#+)(.+?)\n/s';
$line = "##Sub heading\n ###sub-sub heading\n";
$line = preg_replace_callback(
            $regex,
            function($matches){
                $h_num = strlen($matches[1]);
                return "<h$h_num>".$matches[2]."</h$h_num>";
            },
            $line
        );
echo $line;
```

The output would be something like this -

```
<h2>Sub heading</h2> <h3>sub-sub heading</h3>
```

**EDIT**
For the combined problem of using `=` for headings and `#` for sub-headings, the regex gets a bit more complicated, but the principle remains the same using `preg_replace_callback`.
Try this -

```
$regex = '/(?:(#+)(.+?)\n)|(?:(.+?)\n\s*=+\s*\n)/';
$line = "Heading\n=======\n##Sub heading\n ###sub-sub heading\n";
$line = preg_replace_callback(
            $regex,
            function($matches){
                //var_dump($matches);
                if($matches[1] == ""){
                    return "<h1>".$matches[3]."</h1>";  
                }else{
                    $h_num = strlen($matches[1]);
                    return "<h$h_num>".$matches[2]."</h$h_num>";
                }   
            },
            $line
        );
echo $line;
```

Whose Output is -

```
<h1>Heading</h1><h2>Sub heading</h2> <h3>sub-sub heading</h3>
```

Comment: Wrong closing tags ? <\h2> => </h2>

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.But the result shows Sub heading<\h2>

sub-sub heading<\h3>.How to remove </h2> </h3>

Comment: For strict equality you can simple use preg_replace

Comment: Now I am using the below code for equal sign.Is this the right way...$sym1="";
     $sym=substr_count($text, '==');
     for($i=0;$i<$sym;$i++){
     $sym1.="=";
     }
     $text = preg_replace('/(.+?)'.$sym1.'/s', '<h1>$1</h1>', $text);
  $text=str_replace('=','',$text);

Answer (score 1):

Do a preg_match_all like this:

```
$string = "#####asdsadsad";
preg_match_all("/^#/", $string, $matches);
var_dump ($matches);
```

And based on count of matches you can do whatever you want.

Or, use the `preg_replace_callback` function.

```
$input = "#This is my text";
$pattern = '/^(#+)(.+)/';
$mytext = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'parseHashes', $input);
var_dump($mytext);

function parseHashes($input) {
    var_dump($input);
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all('/(#)/', $input[1], $matches);
    var_dump($matches[0]);
    var_dump(count($matches[0]));
    $cnt = count($matches[0]);
    if ($cnt <= 6 && $cnt > 0) {
        return '<h' . $cnt . ' class="if you want class here">' . $input[2] . '</h' . $cnt . '>';
    } else {
        //This is not a valid h tag. Do whatever you want.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use preg_replace_callback.Can you give me an example please..

Comment: The above code shows only length=1 
      0 => string '#' (length=1).How can I get number of hash symbol

Comment: Your's answer also good one.But The exact easy way is the above answer by Kamehameha.Thank you.